# mysqli update from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am stuck on whether the first step is  this the right way and how to proceed to the next step.

on page 1 I have:

```
$query="select  index_member, name from members where active=1 order by name";
$rs=$db->query($query);`
```

I then fill a table with radio dials

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($column == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }   

    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td><td align='center'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$row['index_member']." value='0'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='radio' name=".$row['index_member']." '";
    echo "value='1' checked></td> ";

    $column++;

    if ($column >= 2) {
        echo "</tr>";
        $column=0;
    }
}
```

this shows:

name1 0 1

name2 0 1

name3 0 1

(the 0 and 1 represent the values for the radio button)

and then post to a 2nd page. Doing a `print_r($_POST);` on the second page returns:

```
Array ( 
    [21] => 0 
    [7] => 1 
    [12] => 0 
    [20] => 1 
    [33] => 0 
    [22] => 1......
```

I want to cycle through `update members set active = *value* where member= *key*;`

I am unsure how to extract the array info and insert it into the variables of the query.

Additionally, are there any special considerations for mysqli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest name them this way:

```
echo '<td>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="member['.$row['index_member'].']" value="0" />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="member['.$row['index_member'].']" value="1" checked />';
echo '</td>';
```

Then, just treat it like a normal `$_POST`.

The indices are the `index_member`, the pair value are the values:

```
$members = $_POST['member'];

$sql = 'UPDATE members SET active = ? WHERE index_member = ?';
$update = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($members as $index_member => $val) {
    $update->bind_param('ii', $val, $index_member);
    $update->execute();
}
```

Comment: without testing I am am trying to understand what you put. wouldn't `"member['.$row['index_member'].']"` result in `member12` as the name? If so, then  how do you just get `$_POST['member']`

Comment: @BillFlippen no, theoretically, it will look like `member[12]` thats much manageable that way,

Comment: @BillFlippen when you explicitly call `$_POST['member']`, you are given an array of key-pair values which comprises the index (key of the index member) and its corresponding active value. you wouldn't want to loop the whole `$_POST`, wouldn't you :)

Comment: ok i missed the quotes placement. I will have digest this and follow up on it a bit. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok that work great, but now I have strange feeling the submit isn't the best way to do this. In essence my submit is updating every entry. At most I can see me having a few hundred entries, currently I have about 50 and it is taking a few seconds to update them all. Now to search to see how to submit ONLY CHANGED radio buttons.

Comment: @BillFlippen actually i had this similar issue with one of the projects i made before, but i kinda devised a way wherein you only get the ones you changed using jquery. of course this must be fitting to another question i think

Comment: yes, my searches so far haven't revealed much and I am not ready to venture out from strict php just yet. project is more of a learning exercise rather than something that has to be done.

Comment: @BillFlippen well i guess if you want to do it strictly with PHP, then you need a comparision, between the array with holds the default values, and the one with the selected values, mostlikely just use an in-built array function (i guess `array_diff`), then that would be the only ones that has been changed, then update